# How to generate a puma.sock file on production ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, puma

Deployin my Ruby on Rails app on AWS EC2 with puma. When I hit url nginx gives an error that puma.sock not exists.

```
*connect() to unix:/home/ubuntu/peatio/shared/sockets/puma.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 44.225.84.206, server: localhos
```

How can I generate puma.sock?

config/puma.rb

```
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 2 }
threads threads_count, threads_count
port ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "production" }
plugin :tmp_restart
# Change to match your CPU core count
workers 1
# Min and Max threads per worker
threads 1, 6
app_dir = File.expand_path("../..", __FILE__)
shared_dir = "#{app_dir}/shared"
# Default to production
rails_env = ENV['RAILS_ENV'] || "production"
environment rails_env
# Set up socket location
bind "unix://#{shared_dir}/shared/sockets/puma.sock"
# Logging
stdout_redirect "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stdout.log", "#{shared_dir}/log/puma.stderr.log", true
# Set master PID and state locations
pidfile "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.pid"
state_path "#{shared_dir}/pids/puma.state"
activate_control_app
on_worker_boot do
require "active_record"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! rescue ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(YAML.load_file("#{app_dir}/config/database.yml")[rails_env])
end
```

How to generate a puma.sock file?

Comment: Same question as the last time you posted this question: are you *certain* that `unix:/home/ubuntu/peatio/shared/sockets/puma.sock` and `"unix://#{shared_dir}/shared/sockets/puma.sock"` are the same path?

Comment: @anothermh #{shared_dir} is the path of project

Comment: so its the same

Comment: Then Rails isn't starting.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: no .... i left that project :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
`cap production puma:start`